# How to use MEMBER OF in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have seen questions with this error, but either are calling external stores or trying with incompatible types or using a varray. So i setup a very simple example and still i can not make it work.

```
DECLARE 
TYPE mytype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
mytable mytype;
BEGIN
  mytable((mytable.COUNT+1)) := 'COD1';
  mytable((mytable.COUNT+1)) := 'COD2';
  mytable((mytable.COUNT+1)) := 'COD3';
  mytable((mytable.COUNT+1)) := 'COD4';  
  --IF 'COD1' MEMBER OF mytable THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('We have the code'); END IF;
  FOR i IN 1..mytable.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mytable(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I get this if i run it:

```
COD1
COD2
COD3
COD4
```

If i uncomment the IF (what i intend to use) i get this error.

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to MEMBER OF
```

Perhaps I am not using it correctly or something is wrong.

I am trying to use that on a loop, I save the codes that I have used in the "array" then given one code I need to know if it was already used.
My initial solution was to append to a string like ".COD1..COD2." and do a simple INSTR but does not seem right and I like arrays.
I heard of that function (member of) which does what I wanted if only work as I believe it should.

can you tell me How to use correctly, what i am doing wrong or how to solve my problem in a better way?

Almost there...
I change it to

```
-- Declare
TYPE mytype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4) INDEX BY VARCHAR(4);
mytable mytype;
-- Fill
mytable('COD1') := 'COD1'; -- kind of redundant I only need the index
-- The magic
IF mytable.EXISTS('COD1')...
```

But I still feel that there should be a better way.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried to illustrate how you can make use of MEMBER function with NESTED TABLE TYPE. It cannot be used with Asociative arrays. Hope it helps.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
type my_tab
IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
  tab my_tab;
BEGIN
  tab:=my_tab('AVRAJIT','SHUBHOJIT');
  IF 'AVRAJIT' member OF (tab) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Yes');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('No');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: It works even without round brackets:
 IF 'AVRAJIT' member OF tab THEN

Answer (score 5):

MEMBER OF can only be used with nested tables.  You're trying to use it on an associative array.  Here is a nice [explanation of the differences](http://its-all-about-oracle.blogspot.com/2013/06/associative-arrayindex-by-table-vs.html).

Comment: Oh I see thanks, do you happen to know how can i find an element in an assosiative array, for the life of me, I tried googling everything without success.

Comment: You've done it in your edit above.  Use mytable.EXISTS.  Perhaps you should define what you mean by "better way".

Comment: I mean in the way I understand arrays are this way array[index] = value, so a "better way" would be to find the "value" not the "index" which purpose should not be storing the value itself. I might be wrong and if it works...

Comment: You could assign anything for the value, e.g., mytable('COD1') := 1; and the EXISTS test will still work.